# Is there any specific configuration needed to run docker images from a private registry within a crio runtime?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, nexus3

I'm deploying an OKE kubernetes cluster which uses crio as container runtime. I have already configured a reverse proxy nginx for a private registry (with nexus3, and outside the cluster) and tried and succeed locally pulling, pushing and running containers only with docker login <registry.com>.

However when I try to pull those docker images within the cluster it fails with the following message:

Exec commands:

```
crioctl pull <domain.com.br>/imageName:tag --creds user:pass
```

error creating build container: Error initializing source : error pinging docker registry : invalid status code from registry 404 (Not Found)

Following the nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 2;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
        client_max_body_size 0;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
        access_log  /dev/null;
        proxy_intercept_errors off;
        proxy_send_timeout 120;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;

        upstream nexus {
                server nexus-registry:8081;
        }

        upstream registry {
                server nexus-registry:5000;
        }

        server {

                listen 80;
                server_name <my-domain>;

                keepalive_timeout  5 5;
                proxy_buffering    off;

                location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge{
                        allow all;
                        root /usr/share/nginx/html/letsencrypt;
                }

                location / {
                        return 301 https://<my-domain>$request_uri;
                }
        }

        server {
             listen 443 ssl;
             server_name <my-domain>;

             ssl on;
             server_tokens off;
             ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/<my-domain>/fullchain.pem;
             ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/<my-domain>/privkey.pem;
             ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam-2048.pem;

             ssl_buffer_size 8k;
             ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
             ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
             ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
             location / {
                #redirect to docker registry
                if ($http_user_agent ~ docker ) {
                        proxy_pass http://registry;
                }
                proxy_pass http://nexus;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of the client which was trying to pull images from nexus registry. I had to add cri-o with docker so it worked.

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ (docker|cri-o) )
```